# Changing height of Grid in WPF using Storyboard

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I'm trying to change the height of a WPF grid from `0` to `Auto` using Storyboard. I know I can't do it without tricking, so I tried to change the MaxHeight Value, using Databinding in the Storyboard. But I can't make it works (height is always equals to 0). Here is the code I use :

The two visualstates :

```
 <VisualState x:Name="SelectionMode">
      <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentToolGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxHeight)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />                  
           </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
       </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>

 <VisualState x:Name="EditionMode">
      <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentToolGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxHeight)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ElementName=CurrentToolGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" />               
           </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
       </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
```

Here is my grid definition :

```
 <Grid x:Name="CurrentToolGrid" Background="#FFDEDEDE" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto">
      [... some controls that extends the grid's height ...]
 </Grid>
```

Why the height of the `CurrentToolGrid` is always 0 ?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I think you want to hidden ToolGrid when Editing mode, show ToolGrid when SelectionMode, so why not try to set Visibility Property Of ToolGrid between Visible and Collapsed?

Comment: Because I want it to slide up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to following code, I use **TranslateTransform** instead of MaxWidth, it make scense for Slide scenario.The **key** to impl this is StoryBoard should define in resource, then storyboard can find the specify control which binding in doubleanimation.

```
<Window x:Class="SlideUpWPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        x:Name="Window"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="640"
        Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sb1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grdContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ElementName=grdContent, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="sb2">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grdContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{Binding ElementName=grdContent, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform />
                <SkewTransform />
                <RotateTransform />
                <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="EditMode" Storyboard="{StaticResource sb1}" />
                <VisualState x:Name="SelectionMode" Storyboard="{StaticResource sb2}" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Enter Edit Mode">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="EditMode" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Enter Selected Mode">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="SelectionMode" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="grdContent"
              Grid.Row="1"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                    <SkewTransform />
                    <RotateTransform />
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <!--  some content  -->
            <Rectangle Height="65" Fill="LightBlue" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```